# django Microsoft SQL server migrate issue django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, pyodbc

Below is the error I am facing when doing python manage.py migrate after connecting to the MicrosoftSQL Server database in the Django framework. Not able to do migrate and work with that data base

error:

````
```django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The specified
schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. (2760) (SQLExecDirectW)'))``
````

Answer (score 0):

Approach1
I have tried to execute the python manage.py migrate command with admin user
Approach 2:
create a new user using SQL Server Management Studio.

below SQL commands
USE MASTER
CREATE LOGIN myuser WITH PASSWORD='password'
GO
USE mydb
CREATE USER myuser FOR LOGIN myuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Products
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER myuser
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER myuser
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER myuser
GO

use this user in DATABASE of the settings.py